# Using `SELECT` as `RETURN` Argument in Function?

Tags: oracle, functions

Using Oracle, I attempted to write a function that demonstrates how to return the result of a `SELECT ...` query:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(v1 number) RETURN number IS
     BEGIN
      IF TRUE THEN
         RETURN (select 42 from dual);
       ELSE
         RETURN v1;
       END IF;
     END;
```

But it does not compile.

How can I fix the above `IF`'s `RETURN` to return `42`, i.e. the result of `select 42 from DUAL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the result of your query into a variable and return the variable. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_f(v1 number) RETURN number IS
v2 number;
 BEGIN
  IF TRUE THEN
     SELECT 42 into v2 from dual;
     RETURN v2;
   ELSE
     RETURN v1;
   END IF;
 END;
```

Be sure that your query always generates exactly one row. Otherwise you could get an error if no rows returned or if more than one row is returned.